# How Risky is it to Rely Solely on S3 for Backup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've seen many environments where critical data is backed up to Amazon S3 and it is assumed that this will basically never fail.

I know that Amazon reports that data stored in S3 has 99.999999999% durability (11 9's), but one thing that I'm struck by is the following passage from the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DataDurability.html):

> Amazon S3 provides a highly durable storage infrastructure designed
>   for mission-critical and primary data storage. Objects are redundantly
>   stored on multiple devices across multiple facilities in an Amazon S3
>   region.

So, S3 objects are only replicated *within a single AWS region*.  Say there's an earthquake in N. California that decimates the whole region.  Does that mean N. California S3 data has gone with it?

I'm curious what others consider best practices with respect to persisting mission-critical data in S3?

Comment: Where does that 11 9s come from?  That's 1 second of downtime for every 3 millennia.

Comment: It's in the same docs that I linked in the OP (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DataDurability.html).  Keep in mind that is 11 9's of DURABILITY.  Amazon guarantees only 99.99% (4 9's) of AVAILABILITY.

Comment: Ah ok.  Still, it's unclear what that means.  Is that per year?  i.e. you'll lose 1 file out every 1e11 per year?  Sounds just about as meaningless!

Comment: Yep, that's the claim they make. I'm wondering, though, if being limited to a single AWS region makes that a lot riskier than it appears.

Comment: Mind that one AWS Region is composed of multiple Availability Zones geographically apart and Amazon S3 is designed to sustain the concurrent loss of data in two facilities. It would take a hell of an earthquake to sink your objects :)

Comment: While its likely you won't have issues storing your data on S3, you are putting a lot of faith in a single provider. If you have the resources, it may be prudent to have a alternative option to S3 available for use.